# How to ignore specific element in Zoom using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I would like build zoom functionality on specific area (div) of my application page.I have list of % values (200, 100, 50) in dropdown and i achieved it partially using below code.

**Javascript function:**

```
   function ChangeZoom(zoom) {

            var Page = document.getElementById('divGrid');
            Page.style.zoom = zoom;
        }
```

**ASPX Page:**

```
<select name="" id="ddzoom" onchange="ChangeZoom(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
                                            <option value="400%">400%</option>
                                            <option value="200%">200%</option>
                                            <option value="100%" selected="selected">100%</option>
                                            <option value="50%">50%</option>
                                        </select>
```

Above code works well and it will change zoom level of all elements. Now in my case inside this div i have multiple controls of image and i do not want to scale that because my requirement it to change it **src** Path only for optimization of page

i.e. in 100%

```
<img id="MainContent_grid_Image1_0" class="device" src="../../Images/Device/100/5.JPG" ">
```

on 200% i'll change it to **src="../../Images/Device/200/5.JPG**

But what happened it would scale that image also! in that case i need to reduce scale using **style="zoom:50%"** as below.

```
<img id="MainContent_grid_Image1_0" class="device" src="../../Images/Device/200/5.JPG" style="
    zoom: 50%;
">
```

How can i ignore that element in div zoom level or how can i achieve it another easy way?

Also zoom css property is only working with chrome. what i need to to run it in IE & FF?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved above issue myself as below

Just i have taken fix high width according to 100% zoom level so there wouldn't extra scaling on image

```
<img id="MainContent_grid_Image1_0" class="device" src="../../Images/Device/100/5.JPG" height="60" width ="35">.
```

It works well in chrome.